# Prevent express-session from generating session IDs for OPTIONs requests

Tags: express, cookies, cors, express-session

I'm using Svelte with GraphQLClient on the frontend and express and express-session on the backend. I have now understood through the debugger that for *every* request, including OPTIONS/GET/POST etc, express-session is either trying to find or generating a session ID. I would not like it to do that when the HTTP request is OPTIONS, but I don't see how to configure this.

My frontend and backend are on different ports but same domain, so I'm not sure if it's a CORS issue, although CORS is also enabled

```
  const cors = {
    allowedHeaders: [
      'Accept',
      'Authorization',
      'Content-Type',
      'Origin',
      'X-Requested-With',
    ],
    credentials: true,
    methods: 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE',
    origin: dev ? true : env.ORIGIN,
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
  };
```

Session settings

```
  return session({
    cookie: {
      secure,
      domain: secure ? '.x.com' : 'localhost',
    },
    resave: false,
    store: new SessionStore({
      collection: 'sessions',
      uri: db,
    }),
    secret: 'bla',
    saveUninitialized: true,
  });
```

---

On the other hand, is my problem that I'm not sending cookies on OPTIONS requests from the frontend?